# modifying a variable from python module in second script for function in first script

Tags: python, xml

a.py looks like this:

```
user = '0'
xml = '<int>%s</int>'
```

What I'm trying to do is have it so I can use a second script, b.py like this:

```
import a
a.user = '4343'
print a.xml
```

Is this possible? Because I haven't been able to do it. I always get the first variable in the other script. I would rather hold the XML in the second script, because it's so long and makes scrolling through code annoying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible—and, in fact, you're doing it.

It's hard to tell, because you don't have anything that actually *uses* `a.user`. But that's easy to fix:

a.py:

```
user = '0'
xml = '<int>%s</int>'

def foo():
    return xml % (user,)
```

b.py:

```
import a
a.user = '4343'
print a.foo()
```

Now run it:

```
$ python b.py
<int>4343</int>
```

Exactly what you wanted, right?